# Aggregate results from two arrays

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm fairly new to MongoDB and I'm trying to aggregate some stats on a "Matches" collection that looks like this:

```
{
    team1: {
        players: ["player1", "player2"],
        score: 10
    },
    team2: {
        players: ["player3", "player4"],
        score: 5
    }
},
{
    team1: {
        players: ["player1", "player3"],
        score: 15
    },
    team2: {
        players: ["player2", "player4"],
        score: 21
    }
},
{
    team1: {
        players: ["player4", "player1"],
        score: 21
    },
    team2: {
        players: ["player3", "player2"],
        score: 9
    }
},
{
    team1: {
        players: ["player1"],
        score: 5
    },
    team2: {
        players: ["player3"],
        score: 10
    }
}
```

I'm looking to get games won, loss and win/loss ratio by each player. I'm new to aggregate functions and having trouble getting something going. Could someone point me the right direction?

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/

Comment: I would argue in favor of having another collection that stores those stats. Your needs are slightly complicated for aggregation, it might be easier to do a full map reduce operation.

Comment: What do you mean by *I'm looking to get games won, loss and win/loss ratio by each player*? Please elaborate. what's your expected result?

Comment: @user3100115 Player1: 2 games won, 2 games loss, Player 2: 2 games won, 1 game loss, Player3: 1 game won, 3 games loss, Player4: 2 games won, 1 game loss. The win/loss ratio is calculated by dividing the wins by the losses.

Comment: @JaimeRodas As for a different structure, I would aggree that it could be structured better to make things more simple. But the aggregation framework would still handle this much faster than `mapReduce`, and relatively simply still in modern versions.

Comment: Although this operation can be done in multi-stage aggregation framework (as you can see below) but personally I think it's not very efficient with existing structure. However if document structure can be changed at application level, it will be much performant.

Answer (score 3):

Dealing with mutiple arrays in a structure is not really a simple task for aggregation, particularly when your results really want to consider the combination of both arrays.

Fortunately there are a few operations and/or techniques that can help here, along with the fact that each game comprises a "set" of unique players per team/match and results.

The most streamlined approach would be using the features of MongoDB 2.6 and upwards to effectively "combine" the arrays into a single array for processing:

```js
db.league.aggregate([
    { "$project": {
        "players": {
            "$concatArrays": [
                { "$map": {
                    "input": "$team1.players",
                    "as": "el",
                    "in": { 
                        "player": "$$el", 
                        "win": {
                            "$cond": {
                                "if": { "$gt": [ "$team1.score", "$team2.score" ] },
                                "then": 1,
                                "else": 0
                            }
                        },
                        "loss": {
                            "$cond": {
                                "if": { "$lt": [ "$team1.score", "$team2.score" ] },
                                "then": 1,
                                "else": 0
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }},
                { "$map": {
                    "input": "$team2.players",
                    "as": "el",
                    "in": { 
                        "player": "$$el", 
                        "win": {
                            "$cond": {
                                "if": { "$gt": [ "$team2.score", "$team1.score" ] },
                                "then": 1,
                                "else": 0
                            }
                        },
                        "loss": {
                            "$cond": {
                                "if": { "$lt": [ "$team2.score", "$team1.score" ] },
                                "then": 1,
                                "else": 0
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }}
            ]
        }
    }},
    { "$unwind": "$players" },
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$players.player",
        "win": { "$sum": "$players.win" },
        "loss": { "$sum": "$players.loss" }
    }},
    { "$project": {
        "win": 1,
        "loss": 1,
        "ratio": { "$divide": [ "$win", "$loss" ] }
    }},
    { "$sort": { "_id": 1 } }
])
```

This listing is using [`$concatArrays`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/concatArrays/) from MongoDB 3.2, but that acutal operator can just as easily be replaced by [`$setUnion`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setUnion/) considering that the list of players per game is "unique" and therefore a "set". Either operator is basically joining one array with another based on the output of the inner operations.

For those inner operations we are using [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/), which processes each array ( "team1/team2" ) in-line and just does a caculation for each player on whether the game result was a "win/loss". This makes things easier for the following stages.

Though the 3.2 and 2.6 releases for MongoDB both introduced operators for making working with arrays easier, the general principle comes back to that if you want to "aggregate" on data within an array, then you process with [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) first. This exposes each "player" data within each game from the previous mapping.

Now it's just a matter of using [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) to bring together the results for each player, with [`$sum`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/) for each total field. In order to get a "ratio" over the summed results, process with a [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) to introduce the [`$divide`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/divide/) between the result values, then optionally [`$sort`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/) the resulting key for each player.

---

### Older Solution

Prior to MongoDB 2.6, your only real tool for dealing with arrays was first to `$unwind`. So the same principles come into play here:

1. "map" each array with "win/loss".
2. Combine the content per game into one "distinct list"
3. Sum content based on common "player" field

The only real difference in approach is that the "distinct list" per game we are going to be here will be "after" pulling apart the mapped arrays, and instead just returning one document per "game/player" combination:

```js
db.league.aggregate([
    { "$unwind": "$team1.players" },
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id",
        "team1": {
            "$push": {
                "player": "$team1.players",
                "win": { 
                    "$cond": [
                        { "$gt": [ "$team1.score", "$team2.score" ] },
                        1,
                        0
                    ]
                },
                "loss": { 
                    "$cond": [
                        { "$lt": [ "$team1.score", "$team2.score" ] },
                        1,
                        0
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        "team1Score": { "$first": "$team1.score" },
        "team2": { "$first": "$team2" }
    }},
    { "$unwind": "$team2.players" },
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id",
        "team1": { "$first": "$team1" },
        "team2": {
            "$push": {
                "player": "$team2.players",
                "win": { 
                    "$cond": [
                        { "$gt": [ "$team2.score", "$team1Score" ] },
                        1,
                        0
                    ]
                },
                "loss": { 
                    "$cond": [
                        { "$lt": [ "$team2.score", "$team1Score" ] },
                        1,
                        0
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        "type": { "$first": { "$const": ["A","B" ] } }
    }},
    { "$unwind": "$team1" },
    { "$unwind": "$team2" },
    { "$unwind": "$type" },
    { "$group": {
        "_id": {
            "_id": "$_id",
            "player": {
                "$cond": [
                    { "$eq": [ "$type", "A" ] },
                    "$team1.player",
                    "$team2.player"
                ]
            },
            "win": {
                "$cond": [
                    { "$eq": [ "$type", "A" ] },
                    "$team1.win",
                    "$team2.win"
                ]
            },
            "loss": {
                "$cond": [
                    { "$eq": [ "$type", "A" ] },
                    "$team1.loss",
                    "$team2.loss"
                ]
            }
        }
    }},
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id.player",
        "win": { "$sum": "$_id.win" },
        "loss": { "$sum": "$_id.loss" }
    }},
    { "$project": {
        "win": 1,
        "loss": 1,
        "ratio": { "$divide": [ "$win", "$loss" ] }
    }},
    { "$sort": { "_id": 1 } }
])
```

So this is the interesting part here:

```js
    { "$group": {
        "_id": {
            "_id": "$_id",
            "player": {
                "$cond": [
                    { "$eq": [ "$type", "A" ] },
                    "$team1.player",
                    "$team2.player"
                ]
            },
            "win": {
                "$cond": [
                    { "$eq": [ "$type", "A" ] },
                    "$team1.win",
                    "$team2.win"
                ]
            },
            "loss": {
                "$cond": [
                    { "$eq": [ "$type", "A" ] },
                    "$team1.loss",
                    "$team2.loss"
                ]
            }
        }
    }},
```

That basically gets rid of any duplication per game that would have resulted from each `$unwind` on different arrays. Being that when you `$unwind` one array, you get a copy of the whole document for each array member. If you then `$unwind` another contained array, then the content you just "unwound" is also "copied" again for each of those array members.

Fortunately this is fine since any player is only listed once per game, so every player only has one set of results per game. An alternate way to write that stage, would be to process into another array using [`$addToSet`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addToSet):

```js
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id",
        "players": {
            "$addToSet": {
                "$cond": [
                    { "$eq": [ "$type", "A" ] },
                    "$team1",
                    "$team2"
                ]
            }
        }
    }},
    { "$unwind": "$players" }
```

But since that produces another "array", it's a bit more desirable to just keep the results as separate documents, rather than process with `$unwind` again.

So again this is really "joining results into a single distinct list", where in this case since we lack the operators to "join" both "team1" and "team2" together, the arrays are pulled apart and then conditionally "combined" depending on the current "A" or "B" value that is being processed.

The end "joining" looks at many "copies" of data, but there is still essentially only "one distinct player record per game" for each player involved, and since we worked out the numbers before the "duplication" occurred, then it's just really a matter of picking one of them from each game first.

Same end results, by them summing up for each player and calculating from totals.

---

### Conclusion

So you might generally conclude here, that in either case most of the work involved is aimed at getting those two arrays of data into a single array, or indeed into singular documents per player per game in order to come to the simple aggregation for totals.

You might well consider then "that" is probably a better structure for the data than the present format, given your need to aggregate totals from those sources.

---

**N.B**: The `$const` operator is undocumented but has been in place since MongoDB 2.2 with the introduction of the aggregation framework. It serves exactly the same function as [`$literal`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/literal/) ( introduced in MongoDB 2.6 ), and in fact is "exactly" the same thing in the codebase, with the newer definition simply pointing to the older one.

It's used in the listing here as the intended MongoDB targets ( pre 2.6 ) would not have `$literal`, and the other listing is suitable and better for MongoDB 2.6 and upwards. With `$setUnion` applied of course.

Answer (score 0):

Well, honestly I'd like to not do this kind of manipulation in mongoldb as it's not very efficient. However, for sake of argument you can try:

NOTE: following query targets MongoDB version 3.2

```
db.matches.aggregate([
{$project:{_id:1, teams:["$team1","$team2"], 
  tscore:{$max:["$team1.score","$team2.score"]}}},
{$unwind:"$teams"},
{$unwind:"$teams.players"},
{$project:{player:"$teams.players", 
  won:{$cond:[{$eq:["$teams.score","$tscore"]},1,0]},
  lost:{$cond:[{$lt:["$teams.score","$tscore"]},1,0]}}},
{$group:{_id:"$player", won:{$sum:"$won"}, lost:{$sum:"$lost"}}},
{$project:{_id:0, player:"$_id", won:1, lost:1, 
  ratio:{$cond:[{$eq:[0, "$lost"]},"$won", 
  {$divide:["$won","$lost"]}]}}}
])
```

and it will output following from your sample dataset: NOTE: my mathematics could be wrong in calculation of ratio, however, this is not what we are looking here. I'm simply using won/lost

```
{ 
    "won" : NumberInt(2), 
    "lost" : NumberInt(1), 
    "player" : "player4", 
    "ratio" : 2.0
}
{ 
    "won" : NumberInt(1), 
    "lost" : NumberInt(3), 
    "player" : "player3", 
    "ratio" : 0.3333333333333333
}
{ 
    "won" : NumberInt(2), 
    "lost" : NumberInt(1), 
    "player" : "player2", 
    "ratio" : 2.0
}
{ 
    "won" : NumberInt(2), 
    "lost" : NumberInt(2), 
    "player" : "player1", 
    "ratio" : 1.0
}
```

Comment: You might not understand that `teams:["$team1","$team2"]` as a `$project` was not possible until MongoDB 3.2, and would result in an error in earlier versions. As explained, there are "better" alternatives to using `$unwind` ( and notably "a lot" more performant ) as of MongoDB 2.6, which is why the use is minimized in the preferred exaple. So this attempt at being generic is actually constrained by the MongoDB 3.2 release.

Comment: I totally agree with you. This solution is targeted at MongoDB 3.2 as asker didn't mentioned which version he is running. I guess I should clearly state version of MongoDB, this query is tested against. Thanks @BlakesSeven